# adding multiple form data to a single database column

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to add 2 textbox data to a single column in my database.

Sample:

```
<input name="Name" type="text" />
<input name="Address" type="text" />
```

and be put in a single column looking like Name+Address

Thanks

Comment: One column in the database should only ever contain **one item** of information (absolutely fundamental practice in database design - first normal form). Otherwise, your next SO question will be how to parse those two pieces apart from that database column .....

Answer (score 1):

> how to add 2 textbox data to a single column in my database.

You could use a view model.

Domain model:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

View model:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model FooViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Address)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Address)

    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
}
```

Controller:

```
public class SomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Save()
    {
        return View(new FooViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(FooViewModel model)
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo
        {
            Location = model.Name + model.Address
        };

        //... save the foo domain model to your database
        ...       
    }
}
```

Comment: is this the same with checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

Give two same names to inputs 
so that the values will will be saved comma separately